# How to find back a code block in JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I delete a code block in Jupyter Lab accidentally. Can I find it back?

Answer (score 0):

Just type z in command mode
ref: https://blog.csdn.net/eswai/article/details/53642802

Answer (score 0):

Click on the edit tab then hover to the Undo Delete Cells

hope this helps :)